# Is it true that $\# (A([0,1)^n) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n) = |\det A|$, for integral matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Solving a problem I conjectured that
$$\# (A([0,1)^n) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n) = |\det A|$$
where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with integral entries and with non-zero determinant. I tested this with the matrix
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
and works: the only integral points are $\binom{0}{0}$ and $\binom{2}{1}$ (it is important that $[0,1)$ is open at the right), which count exactly $2 = |\det A|$.

I couldn't prove this conjecture or find a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881454/corollary-to-smith-normal-form for instance.

Comment: thanks, i see it now